# How do I properly group by case using a CTE? I am getting an incomplete result

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

below is my SQL query, where I am trying to create a stacked bar chart where different attribute values are grouped by date ranges based off the creation date. Despite my dataset having many values for each combination of attribute and date values, my query only returns a single row, with the range '46-90' broken out by attribute number.

I have looked at some related articles to this query type and I can't find what I am missing (I'm guessing this is one of those times where I've been looking at this too long and a minor little detail is escaping me). Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

```
With CTE As(
  SELECT obj_createDate, obj_att, 
  CASE when DATEDIFF(dd, obj_createdate, getDate()) <= 45 then '<45' 
       when DATEDIFF(dd, obj_createdate, getDate()) > 45 
            AND DATEDIFF(dd, obj_createdate, getDate()) <= 90 then '46-90' 
       when DATEDIFF(dd, obj_createdate, getDate()) > 90 then '>90' 
       end AS DateRange 
  FROM DEMO_OBJECT 
  WHERE DEMO_OBJECT.obj_ot_id = 24 
        AND DEMO_OBJECT.obj_resolveddate IS NULL 
  GROUP BY obj_att, obj_createDate 
) 
SELECT 
 DateRange, 
 COUNT(*) Total,
 sum(case when obj_att = '1' then 1 else 0 end) '1', 
 sum(case when obj_att = '2' then 1 else 0 end) '2', 
 sum(case when obj_att = '3' then 1 else 0 end) '3', 
 sum(case when obj_att = '4' then 1 else 0 end) '4', 
 sum(case when obj_att = '5' then 1 else 0 end) '5' 
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY DateRange;
```

Comment: Try removing `GROUP BY obj_att, obj_createDate` in the CTE.

Comment: Without looking a the data in `obj_createdate` column for the given filter's it is hard to fix

Comment: GROUP BY should be paired with an aggregate function, say, SUM or COUNT

Comment: Thanks @Felix , removing the GROUP BY obj_att, obj_createDate fleshed out all the results for the '46-90' row, the other two date ranges still aren't showing

Comment: @Patrick, are there data in `DEMO_OBJECT` that falls under the other date ranges?

Comment: @FelixPamittan yes there is, about half the data falls in the other two ranges

Comment: Can you verify using `SELECT * FROM CTE`?

Comment: That aside... what happen when the result is exactly `45`?

Comment: @Felix, sure thing, that query returned 950/1996 rows, all in the '46-90' range. Just to clarify, all the rows have a creation date.